# Android Studio 2.1 :Failed to resolve: com.android.databinding:adapters:1.1

Tags: android, data-binding

Today I update my android studio from 2.0 to 2.1
when I rebuild my project,there are some error like this:

[some error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIkRZ.png)

I use data binding in my project.When I use Android studio 2.0,everything is ok.

I find that,there is no databinding1.1 in jcenter 
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/databinding/ 
the newest version is 1.0

how can i fix it

Comment: can you share your full gradle file ?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same question and I updated Google Repository and Android Support library in SDK Manager,it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I know how to fix this.
there are some problem in gradle2.1
[I update my Android Gradle plugin to version 2.1.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSy5t.png)

when I set the Android Gradle version to 2.0,every thing is ok.

```html
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```